# Python matching items across dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have found lot of questions where people are looking to match items in lists but my question is slightly different causing some trouble. I'm using Python 3.6 on a windows 7 machine.

Pretend that I am a CEO for a grocery store chain, every week I get a excel file with the amount of inventory at each store, for each item. Where there are 2 columns, first column the city of the store and the name of the item, and the second column the number of items. Each item has 4 white spaces before each of the items, where as the city has no white spaces, however both are in the same column.

```
|New York   |NAN|
|   Apples  |10 |
|   Oranges |20 |
|   Pears   |30 |
|Los Angeles|NAN|
|   Apples  |20 |
|   Oranges |40 |
|Dallas     |NAN|
|   Apples  |30 |
|   Oranges |60 |
|   Pears   |90 |
```

This needs to be uploaded to a server once a week for inventory control. I have a cross reference with SKU's that relate to each store and item also in a pandas data frame.

Here comes the tough part. I now want to match this with my SKU's so that I can properly get the inventory for each sku for each store. My inventory dataframe is:

```
|City|Item     |#|
|NY  | Apples  |?|
|NY  | Oranges |?|
|NY  | Pears   |?|
|LA  | Apples  |?|
```

My thought was to first look in the list for New York, once I find New York, iterate down by line til I find my fruit. Problem is as shown, LA doesn't have Pears, if New York runs out the line will be missing, not just a 0 for the inventory. So a for loop will iterate til it gets to Dallas and use its inventory instead of returning that New York doesn't have pears. Concisely, How do I make sure the for loop doesn't go past the city I'm trying to get and return a different cities inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the data into pandas directly, parse the Excel file using [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) to reformat the file with proper `city | product | count` entries and ingest that into a dataframe. You should then be able to cross reference this list against the SKUs using a standard [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)